# Bootstrap validator submit button is not working with react api calls

Tags: forms, validation, reactjs

I'm using bootstrap validator plugin to validate my form in react app. Everything is working fine but while integrating with api the sumbit button is not working, i mean while I click on the submit button the api call is not happening, the page is immediately gets refreshed. Below is the code

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick=
{this.HandleClick}>Submit</button>
```

On HandleClick function we have the api call using Axios.post and I'm posting the form data to server. when we changed the type to button the call will happen and its working, but I need the button to be hidden until the form gets validated thats why i changed type as submit. Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you getting any console error ?

Comment: No...Getting some warnings only, but the page is refreshed after I click on submit. Below is the warning Im getting

    Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a 
    descendant of <form>. See ContentComponent > form > ... > 
    RadioButtons > form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is immediately refreshed because a `<button type="submit"` automatically submit the form when you click on it.

You can replace `type="submit"` by `type="button"` or if you want to keep `type="submit"` you have to call the `preventDefault` function in your handler to not submit the form automatically

```
function HandleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```